# References and copies in python

Tags: python, variables, reference

So i've been trying a few things out in python and happened to come across this:

```
>>> a = 10
>>> b = 10
>>> a is b
True
```

Apparently when creating the variable `b` Python notices that there is already another(different) variable with the value 10 and simply creates a reference to it (simply to save memory, maybe?). Since integers are immutable (at least I think they are) it makes some kind of sense.
But then i tried the same thing with a bigger number and got this:

```
>>> a = 100200103847239642631982367
>>> b = 100200103847239642631982367
>>> a is b
False
```

Here, for some reason Python seems to create another `int` object instead of making the variable `b` a reference to the variable `a`, which does not make sense to me. Assuming the reason the references created in first example is to save memory, wouldn't it be even more efficient to create a reference in the latter case also since the numbers are way bigger?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python normally caches integers between -5 and 256 (although this may differ between implementation); when two names point to the same cached integer, they have the same id, and thus point to the same object:

```
>>> c = 10
>>> d = 10
>>> id(c) == id(d)
True
>>> c is d
True
```

Once you breach that cache threshold, however, the ids will change:

```
>>> e = 256
>>> d = 256
>>> id(e) == id(d)
True
>>> d = 257
>>> e = 257
>>> id(d) == id(e)
False
>>> d is e
False
>>> f = -5
>>> g = -5
>>> id(f) == id(g)
True
>>> f = -6
>>> g = -6
>>> id(f) == id(g)
False
```

You are seeing the same effect.

Keep in mind that `is` does not compare values, do not use `is` when you really mean "equals to":

```
>>> 10 * 1000 is 10000
False
>>> 10 * 1000 == 10000
True
```

Comment: I was reading the docs trying to understand this behaviour, but couldn't find how it caches small data. Thanks for your clarification !!

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but why exactly are the limits for caching at -5 and 256? Wouldn't caching make more sense the larger the numbers get?

Comment: @Parzival the point of the caching is for those numbers that appear frequently (e.g. as literals) in code; although caching a larger number saves more memory in theory, they don't appear often enough to be worth it. Caching your `0`s and `-1`s, on the other hand...